# Audio streaming from java not working but video works fine

Tags: java, javascript, html, struts2

I'm new to Struts 2 . Now developing a gallery page in a web project. In that i have to show images/audio/video files in a pop up without page loading. I succeeded that in Images & Video files working fine, but not Audio files. My struts action as follows.

```xml
<action name="download" class="com.mkyong.common.action.DownloadAction">
 <result name="success" type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
  <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
  <param name="bufferSize">256</param>
 </result>
</action>
```

And my class file is

```
try {
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\ESS_GALLERY\\2451252452\\Gallery\\Audios\\audio_2.wav"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And jsp(HTML) code is

```html
<object id='tempAud1' name="emQTPlayer" height="45px" width="120px"
    style="behavior: url(#BinaryBehaviorID)"
    codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
    classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B">
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="src"
        value="<s:property value="mediaAud[0].fileLocation"/>" />
    <param name="controller" value="true" />
    <param name="type" value="video/quicktime" />
    <param name="align" value="bottom" />
    <param name="border" value="0" />
    <%--<param name="wmode" value="transparent">--%>
    <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
    <embed id='tempAud2' name="emQTPlayer" type="video/quicktime"
        autoplay="false" height="45px" width="120px" align="top" border="0"
        controller="true" postdomevents="true"
        pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
        showcontrols="true" src='' />
</object>
```

. 
In that i'll set the src at the onclick event...

Comment: When you type in the action in the browser do you get back an audio file? That is can you save it to disk and play it? If you can't the problem is with the action, otherwise the content type can not be handled by the browser/tag or the parameters for the tag are incorrect.

Comment: When i give the download.action directly in the browser, it asks to download it as download.action(since i didn't provide attachment paramenter for filename) ,then i open with any media player it works fine.. Is there any problem or anything special i have to do for Audio files alone? I've seen some pages that java won't support many audio file formats like that ?

Comment: Well the data is clearly getting to you... The issue is with the browser, but the server might not be helping enough. The tag clearly states the media type but who knows maybe it still needs an accurate mime type, so check that the server is providing it also try using that downloaded file "download.action" from a local source and see if the browser wants a more reasonable file extension. I bet different browsers will be more or less flexible with this issue.

Comment: I changed content type and now it works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the content type parameter as follows..

```
<action name="download" class="com.mkyong.common.action.DownloadAction">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
          <param name="contentType">audio/mpeg</param>
          <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
          <param name="bufferSize">256</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

This works fine for audio files....

Comment: +1 I like it when people figure it out and post the answers for others.

Answer (score 0):

Is it normal that you are not providing the source to `<embed>` object ?

Try changing it to

```
<embed id='tempAud2' name="emQTPlayer" type="video/quicktime"
    autoplay="false" height="45px" width="120px" align="top" border="0"
    controller="true" postdomevents="true"
    pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
    showcontrols="true" src='<s:property value="mediaAud[0].fileLocation"/>' />
```

Comment: sorry Andrea Ligios, IE object tag src also will be a blank one.. I mentioned there wrong. I'll set src('http://localhost:8080/propjectname/download.actio') only at the time of clicking to reduce the server load. I'm bit confused when it works for images and video files in IE,Firefox why it fails with audio alone?

Comment: I hope its a typo because it should be `donwload.action`, with the final n. I've not understand completely what are you doing, but I suggest you to start with a minimal, working version, and then to do the tune-up for performances...

Comment: here i provided the sample code for just playing one file on the browser.But atually i have show all file names in gallery page when user clicks file name file will be played on a pop up. thats why i left the src blank and assigning it on run time.My doubt is there any problem with audio file formats in JAVA?

Comment: Don't know, never done :/ You may want to try using HTML5 audio (more documented, just as a test to correctyl set up your server side), like described here: http://html5center.sourceforge.net/Unlocking-the-power-of-HTML5-audio , and to try out the Java AudioInputStream instead of the FileInputStream: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html Hope that helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks Andrea , but my client's requirement is IE8 compatibility. So i can't use in my project. Ay how i'll try using that, whether it works or not.....

Comment: I mean using HTML5 on client side to test that server side is all good... then come back to flash again :/